varible not changing PyQt6
I am writing a simple timer (in PyQt6), and I am trying to implement a pause and un-pause function. Although this should be simple enough, the varible timerRunning is not changing.
My Code:
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6 import uic
import sys
import time
import threading

class MainUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainUI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('test.ui', self)
        self.show()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setDesktopFileName("ftimer")
window = MainUI()
timerRunning = None

def UpdateLabel(seconds, label):
    
    tminutes = int((seconds / 60) % 60)
    tseconds = seconds % 60
    label.setText(f"{tminutes} : {tseconds}")

def StartTimer():
    timerRunning = True

def Timer(label, seconds):
    
    while timerRunning:
        seconds = seconds - 1
        UpdateLabel(seconds, label)
        time.sleep(1)
        app.processEvents()

def StopTimer():
    timerRunning = False

seconds = 300
timer = threading.Thread(target=Timer, args=(window.Time, seconds, ))
timer.start()
#window.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
window.setWindowTitle("Focus Timer")
window.StartTimer.clicked.connect(StartTimer)
window.StopTimer.clicked.connect(StopTimer)
#window.setWindowOpacity(0.5)
app.exec()

My UI File:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>763</width>
    <height>275</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: #282A2E;</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QProgressBar" name="pbar">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>591</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">

QProgressBar::chunk {
    background-color: #02ad5a;
    width: 20px;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="value">
     <number>100</number>
    </property>
    <property name="format">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="StartTimer">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Ubuntu Mono</family>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">color: #aabdb4;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Start</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="StopTimer">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>580</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Ubuntu Mono</family>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">color: #aabdb4;
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Stop</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="Time">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>210</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>361</width>
      <height>91</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Ubuntu</family>
      <pointsize>72</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">color: #aabdb4</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>5 : 00</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignmentFlag::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>

As you can see, I have buttons that line up to StartTimer and StopTimer, but timerRunning stays None.
I tried kill the Thread for timer, and that caused it to crash. I tried multiproccess, but that straight up didn't work, and I tried QThread, which also gave me problems

timerRunning is a local variable in StartTimer and StopTimer.  If you want to ASSIGN to a global within a function, you must include global timerRunning at the top of that function.

It's also worth noticing that global variables are usually frown upon, especially in OOP. While, for this simple case, using global timerRunning (as suggested above) may be acceptable, you should normally avoid that to begin with unless you really know what you're doing and the result of doing it. Also: 1. UI elements are not thread safe, and should NEVER be accessed from external threads (as you do with UpdateLabel() from Timer()); 2. As the processEvents() docs clearly explain, it only works for events in the »

» calling thread, so what you're doing is fundamentally pointless, other than inappropriate; 3. in order to provide clear readability, capitalized names should only be used for classes or constants, not for functions or attributes (see the official Style Guide for Python Code); 4. if you just want to call a function at regular intervals (and that function isn't blocking), threading is the wrong choice. Use QTimer instead. 5. use global functions with awareness: in OOP contexts you should properly create instance methods instead.

Could you show me how to correctly implement this; I am not the most informed on things like thread safety and such.

Sorry but no, as the question is closed and also answering it would mean to completely rewrite the code from scratch, which would go beyond the scope of the question: it would be a tutorial or example code, and that's not the scope of StackOverflow. I suggest you to do some research about OOP (in general, and in Python), as 99% of the time you'll need to properly use subclassing instead of basic functions, at least with Qt (but that's also true for many other modules). Then look up for basic PyQt related tutorials, including those about threading.

bro, i went through tutorial hell. I watched a 14 hr Python course. I am just new to PyQt and threading
